# C# entendiendo herencia

Tags: c#

Me surgio un problema entendiendo herencias, yo tengo mi superclase "servivo" que tiene un constructor el cual recibe un string, que seria el nombre del servivo , ademas de esto tiene un metodo llamado "respira" el cual imprime en pantalla string+"respira". Okey entonces creo mi subclase humano que contiene el metodo "hablo"que imprime en pantalla string+hablo.
Entonces el problema surge cuando instancio un objeto de la clase humano el por que no se... como poder agregar el parametro string que tendria que recibir de servivo, es decir no se si se puede colocar un parametro que recibia la super clase.

PREGUNTA
"servivo" necesita un string de parametro , entonces cuando quiero instanciar un "humano"(subclase de servivo) y quiero pasarle el parametro string, para que se asigne a la variable declarada y solicitada por el constructor de "servivo" como lo hago, bah si es que se puede...

```
   humano A = new humano("shiki") ;

        A.respira();
        A.hablo();



        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
class servivo
{
    public string var="default";
    public void respira()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} respira",var );

    }
    public servivo(string var2)
    {
        this.var = var2;
    }
}
class humano:servivo
{


    public void hablo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} habla",var);
    }
    //RESPUESTA COMPLETA

    public humano(string auxiliar) : base(auxiliar)
    {
        this.var = auxiliar;
    }
```

Solo para salir de dudas probe el codigo de esas dos maneras y funciono pero entro la duda y ante la duda pregunto, cuando pongo `public humano(string auxiliar) : base(auxiliar) { }` Estoy diciendo con este constructor de subclase y este parametro, utilizo base y le digo pasalo como parametro a mi super clase?

Ah y gracia de nuevo por la ayuda! lei la doc de base marcado y puntuado.

```
    public humano(string auxiliar) : base(auxiliar) 
{
 this.var = auxiliar;
 } 
public humano(string auxiliar) : base(auxiliar) 
{ }
```

Comment: "servivo" necesita un string de parametro , entonces cuando quiero instanciar un "humano"(subclase de servivo) y quiero pasarle el parametro string, para que se asigne a la variable declarada y solicitada por el constructor de "servivo" como lo hago, bah si es que se puede....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### La respuesta que quieres:

> Simplemente realiza:
>
> ```
> class humano : servivo 
>    {
>        // ....
>        public humano(string nombre) : base(nombre)
>        {
>            // Resto de tu logica ...
>        }
>    }
> ```
>
> Basicamente es como aplicar herencia a los metodos o funciones, en ese fragmento de codigo lo que hace es que al llamar al constructor de la clase `humano`, se llama al constructor de tu "superclase" antes de realizar el resto de las acciones del constructor de `humano`.

### Pero, para que entiendas un poco la herencia:

- Herencia: Es la propiedad de la programacion orientada a objetos *(POO)* que *en parte* permite la modificacion del comportamiento de un objeto.

Ese es el concepto que has entendido bien hasta ahora.

Supongamos que tengamos la siguiente clase:

```
public class Cosa
{
    public Cosa(string nombre)
    {
        Nombre = nombre;
    }
    public string Nombre { get; private set; }
}
```

Definimos el constructor de la clase `Cosa` y tenemos una propiedad comun llamada `Nombre`, pero, la clase no es capaz de hacer nada por si sola, es entonces que se procede a heredar de las clases como esta, heredemosla:

```
public class Televisor : Cosa 
{
    public int Canal { get; set; }
    public Televisor() : base("Televisor")
    {
        Canal = 1; // Ajustamos el TV para estar en el canal 1.
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo he hecho lo mismo que en el caso que preguntas, si te fijas, en el constructor de `Televisor()` he puesto a su lado `: base("Televisor")`, esto es para que se llame al constructor de `Cosa(string)` antes de realizar las acciones del constructor de la clase `Television`, como mencione arriba, es como aplicar la herencia a una funcion; al utilizar la palabra clave `base`, se puede especificar cualquier metodo que produzca el comportamiento de la clase principal, por lo que con un `base.NombreDelMetodo()` basta para realizarlo en cualquier otro metodo.

Si hacemos dentro del constructor de `Television` lo siguiente:

```
public Television() : base("Television")
{
    // resto del codigo
    System.Console.WriteLine(Nombre); 
}
```

Imprimira `"Television"`, debido a que ya ajustamos el constructor de la clase *madre*, *base* o *"superclase" (Como quieras llamarlo)* para que realice las acciones necesarias.

Dentro de este campo, C# incluye clases abstractas y funciones virtuales, con el objetivo de que puedas hacer tu objeto aun mas abstracto, pero todo depende de lo que necesites.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! perdon por la prsgunta confusa, es que al no entender como hacerlo me confundi bastante.